# PWA generic start_url

Tags: javascript, vue.js, progressive-web-apps

I have vue app which is also PWA. The PWA works just fine as intended but the problem is that I am using the generic paths for my web app. That means to open the correct page I am using the path /test/**${user}** . That means when user installs app he is automatically redirected to start path "website.com" not "website.com/test/uniqueid". So my question is - is it possible to set up start_url when user installs the PWA so when he launches the app it redirects him straight to "website.com/test/uniqueid"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is going to help for someone else but I found this hacky solution which works but it has some of its flaws - for example if the user deletes his localstorage.

I added an event listener for 'appinstalled' basically checking when user installs the PWA and when he does I setup localStorage variable

```
window.addEventListener("appinstalled", () => {
            localStorage["istallURL"] = window.location.pathname;
        });
```

After that (In my case) in router.js inside root path I am checking if this localStorage value exists if it does I redirect user to saved path from localhost variable

```
{
path: "/",
        name: "redirect",
        beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
            const installedFrom = localStorage["installURL"];
            if (installedFrom) {
                window.location.replace(installURL);
            } else {
                window.location.href = "https://youtube.com/";
            }
            next();
        },
}
```

Should be easy to adapt it for other frameworks or non framework app, do the same thing before mounting your application :)

Comment: Thanks  @Jonas Tamoševičius for the answer, it really helped me. I was able to add my check in the redirect instead, rather than using a beforeEnter hook.

Just another use cases, as I was already redirecting my home route to login

`{
    path: "",
    redirect: (_) => {
      const installedFrom = localStorage.getItem("installURL");
      if (installedFrom) {
        return { path: installedFrom };
      }
      return { path: "/login" };
    },
  },`

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you wanna do is:

1. Save the PWA to Home Screen as https://www.mypwa.com
2. https://www.mypwa.com is your sign-in page.
3. After user sign-in, you redirect to https://www.mypwa.com/user1001

Comment: Adding sign in screen is not an option, it breaks the whole purpose of the application... I wish that would be the way

Comment: Oh. Ok. Well, in that case, you first visit `https://www.mypwa.com/user1001` then save it to Home Screen. This would require each user to save their own unique URL to Home Screen.